# How to Decode ionCube encrypted files?

Tags: php, encryption, ioncube

I am customizing geodesic classified, my client has not given me access to a licence file (rather I have not asked him about this).

I am able to customize it from the admin panel, but I want to customize it on my local system.

But when I tried to do this it get redirected to site off page.

I think it is because of the `product.php` file code (I have same code as this one):

[What does this PHP do? Is it an encoder/decoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3884916)

Comment: I don't know exactly , but I think this code encrypts php files (as I read it here).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ionCube (at least when it was PHP Accelerator) compiled PHP to bytecode prior to encoding.

This eliminates the source code entirely, and even if you were able to reverse the encoding process, you would still be left with compiled opcodes, not source.

The ionCube loader decodes the bytecode, which then does not need to be parsed, and is executed directly by the PHP virtual machine.

If I recall correctly, the encoder also performs optimisations and obfuscations on the bytecode, that help prevent decompilation.

Comment: Free decompilers do exist, I think they turn the opcodes into source.

Comment: @Shaquin They wont necessarily replicate the exact source, and may even get it wrong, due to the bytecode optimisations.

Comment: @Leigh I tried one, and it even kept the function-name case.

Comment: @uınbɐɥs could you present an example of the one you used?

Comment: I've used many decoders on the files that I own, and most of the times (90% success rate) they decode perfectly.

Comment: @Ejaz please share how you decoded it :)

Comment: @jameshwartlopez You can try "easytoyou" decoder.

Comment: @Sanjyot Shah  This page redirects me to a porn page after clicking download.

Comment: @ViktorJoras - Which page? I have not posted any page urls on this question?